# Delete folder if it exists in PowerShell

Tags: file-system, powershell

In my PowerShell script I'm trying to delete a folder, but only if it exists:

```
if (Test-Path $folder) { Remove-Item $folder -Recurse; }
```

I find myself repeating this combination of cmdlets quite a few times, and wished I had something like this:

```
# Pseudo code:
Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -IgnoreNonExistentPaths
```

Is there a way to do something like that? A different command, or an option I've missed from [the `Remove-Item` documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849765.aspx) perhaps? Or is the only way to DRY out this bit of code to write my own cmdlet that combines `Test-Path` and `Remove-Item`?

Comment: You may be looking for [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Mast, an alias is just an alternative name for a command. You can't specify parameters or anything in an alias definition.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I assume you're just trying to avoid the error message in case it doesn't exist.

What if you just ignore it:

```powershell
Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
```

If that's not what you want, I would recommend writing your own function:

```powershell
function Remove-ItemSafely {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [String[]]
    $Path ,

    [Switch]
    $Recurse
)

    Process {
        foreach($p in $Path) {
            if(Test-Path $p) {
                Remove-Item $p -Recurse:$Recurse -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `-ErrorAction Ignore` would also ignore security errors.

Answer (score 8):

It is better to use pipeline syntax. If there are no files, then nothing will happen:

```
Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

Comment: The `-Recurse` should be on `Remove-Item` if you want it to work correctly, otherwise the directories won't be deleted unless they have no files inside. Even that way though, this won't delete `$folder`, only its contents, so it's good but subtly different.

Comment: does not delete an empty $folder

Comment: Sorting the items by full path and then reversing the list would ensure that children get deleted before their parents, preventing nasty "Are you sure?" prompts.

Answer (score 4):

This will delete an empty folder as well and still propagates errors if files cannot be deleted

```
Get-childItem .idea\caches -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

The most correct option for exceptions would be the `if (test-path $p) { rm $p }` version